# Connecting to FTP server over password protected proxy in php

Tags: php, proxy, ftp

I'm trying to connect to a password protected ftp server over a also password protected HTTP squid proxy with the PHP FTP functions.
These are my variables:

```
$ftp_server = "abc.def.com";
$ftp_port = 22;
$ftp_user = "uvw";
$ftp_pass = "xyz";
$proxy_server = "www-cache";
$proxy_port = "8080";
$proxy_user = "qwe";
$proxy_pass = "rty";
```

Here is, what I tried:

```
$path = "test.txt";
$chronosPath = "webroot/files/uploads/";

echo "Experiment 1\n";

$conn = ftp_connect($proxy_user.":".$proxy_pass."@".$proxy_server, $proxy_port);
$login = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user."@".$ftp_server, $ftp_pass);

var_dump($conn);
var_dump($login);


echo "Experiment 2\n";

$stream_options = array(
    'ftp' => array(
        'proxy' => $proxy_user.":".$proxy_pass."@".$proxy_server.":".$proxy_port
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$file = fopen("ftp://".$ftp_user.":".$ftp_pass."@".$ftp_server."/test.txt", "r", false, $context);
echo fread($file,20);

echo "Experiment 3\n";

$curl = curl_init();

$file = fopen($chronosPath.$path, 'w');
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "ftp://".$ftp_user.":".$ftp_pass."@".$ftp_server.":".$ftp_port."/".$path,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FILE => $file,
    CURLOPT_PROXY => $proxy_server,
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => $proxy_port,
    CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => $proxy_user.":".$proxy_pass,
));
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
```

And here is, what I got:

> Experiment 1
>
> Warning Error: ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Beim Datenbankaufruf ist ein nicht behebbarer
>   Fehler aufgetreten. (German for "The database call resultet in an
>   unsolvable error)  in [path]
>
> Warning Error: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in [path]
>
> bool(false)
>
> NULL
>
> Experiment 2 Warning Error: fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Unknown Host.  in [path]
>
> Warning Error: fopen(ftp://...@tascloud.de/test.txt): failed to open
>   stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Unknown Host. 
>   in [path]
>
> Warning Error: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in [path]
>
> Experiment 3

Experiment 3 results in creating a txt file containing the html source code of a squid error page saying

> Access Denied.
>
> Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed
>   at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is
>   incorrect.
>
> Your cache administrator is root@localhost.

Comment: what is the error that you have encountered?

Comment: I added the three ways I tried and the errors I occured. Experiment 3 at least worked for another sftp.

Comment: Did you find a solution?